# Can't start a simple view with MVVMCross Xamarin IOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

Please help!

Just spend more than 8 hours trying to get ONE simple view presented in iOS, but it is not working. No idea whats going on.

This is my code.
Setup.cs

```
public class Setup : MvxIosSetup
{
    public Setup(MvxApplicationDelegate applicationDelegate, UIWindow window)
        : base(applicationDelegate, window)
    {
    }
    public Setup(MvxApplicationDelegate applicationDelegate, IMvxIosViewPresenter presenter)
        : base(applicationDelegate, presenter)
    {
    }

    protected override void InitializeIoC()
    {
        base.InitializeIoC();
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<ILanguageService>(() => new LanguageService());
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<ISoundPlayerService>(() => new SoundPlayerService());
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IAlertService>(() => new AlertService());
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<ITagManagerService>(() => new TagManagerService());
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IBackCompatService>(() => new BackCompatService());
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IPlatformService>(() => new PlatformService());
    }

    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        return new App();
    }

    protected override IMvxTrace CreateDebugTrace()
    {
        return new DebugTrace();
    }
}
```

AppDelegate.cs

```
[Register("AppDelegate")]
public partial class AppDelegate : MvxApplicationDelegate
{
    public override UIWindow Window
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        var presenter = new MvxIosViewPresenter(this, Window);

        var setup = new Setup(this, presenter);
        setup.Initialize();

        var startup = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
        startup.Start();

        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        return true;
    }
}
```

SplashView

```
public partial class SplashView : MvxViewController
{
    public SplashView() : base("SplashView", null)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<SplashView, SplashViewModel>();
        set.Apply();
    }

    public new SplashViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return (SplashViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
        set { base.ViewModel = value; }
    }
}
```

Now the error I'm getting when I run this is:
MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxException: Failed to construct and initialize ViewModel for type SplashViewModel from locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator - check InnerException for more information

Comment: What happens in App?

Comment: Need to see SplashViewModel.cs and App.cs files to determine the issue. That error is typically thrown when there in a dependency being injected into the ViewModel that was never registered with the IoC container.